# boost::scoped_lock not working (for me)

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex, scoped-lock

I am extending a code base,Have a look at the following code snippet taken out of a class. I made it as simple as possible not to confuse you:

```
std::queue< boost::shared_ptr<const Item> > _container;
boost::mutex _mutex;
//...
void foo(Item *item)
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(_mutex);
    std::cout << "enter " << _container.size() << "  " << this << std::endl;
    boost::shared_ptr<const Item> instr(item);
    _container.push( instr );

    // we only need to signal when size turns from 0 --> 1
    if (_container.size() == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "SIGNALLING" << "  " << this << std::endl;
        signal();//pop the _container until empty
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout <<"NOT SIGNALLING " << _container.size() << "  " << this << std::endl;
    }
}
```

and I get this in stdout:

```
enter 0  0xe919f0
enter 1  0xe919f0
NOT SIGNALLING 2  0xe919f0
enter 2  0xe919f0
NOT SIGNALLING 3  0xe919f0
```

....and so on. `signal()`  is not called. I printed `this` to show that we are operating on the same object.

How possibly/in what kind of scenarios can happen? `'foo is entered twice initially (and messes with the rest of the logic) while it is being protected by a mutex!

I appreciate your solutions.
Thank you

Comment: That can not be happening in provided code. Something else is at play.

Answer (score -1):

> How possibly/in what kind of scenarios can happen? `'foo is entered twice initially (and messes with the rest of the logic) while it is being protected by a mutex!

This would happen when another thread accesses `_container` without synchronizing on *the same `mutex`*.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the OP's question.

Comment: No, it does not. His issue is that he is seeing two entrance into the function with no exit between them, which should not happen given the mutex.

Comment: @SergeyA Oh. Yeah. Good point. Didn't read the trace close enough (focused on the branch taken). In that case, it's [UB all the way.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)